# Ignore error when importing users to Google Suite

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I am importing users to Google Suite from a Google sheet using Google Apps Script. I have made "custom attributes" in Google Admin Console, some of them are set to type email. Everything works great except when one user lack those email addresses.

My users are kids, and the emailaddresses are to the kid's parents. One kid might have 1 parent and 1 email. Other kids have 4 parents and 4 emails.

If all variables (epost1, epost2, epost3 and epost4) are filled with email-addresses the user is added. If one of the variables are empty, the script stops with the following message:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.users.insert failed
> with error: Invalid Input: custom_schema (line 272, file
> "nyeMedlemmer")

I tried to put an if-statement in the code, but that was not possible. Is there a way I can tell the script to just ignore those errors?

My code (after the variables are set):

```
var user = {
  primaryEmail: epost,
  name: {
    givenName: fmnavn,
    familyName: etternavn
  },
 
  addresses: [
    {
    type: "home",
    formatted: adr
    },
    {
    type: "other",
    formatted: adr2
    },
    {
    type: "home",
    postalCode: postnr
    }   
  ],
  phones: [
    {
      value: mobil,
      type: "home"
    }
  ],
  emails: [
    {
      address: epostPriv,
      type: "home"
    }
  ],
  recoveryEmail: epost1,
  locations: [
    {
      floorName: grad,
      type: "desk",
      area: "desk"
    }
  ], 
  gender: {
    type: kjonn
  },
  
 orgUnitPath: "/Speidere/Stifinnere/"+tropp,

 customSchemas: {
    Personlig_informasjon: {
      skole: skolen,
      hensyn: hensynet,
     bursdag: dato
    },
    Innmeldingssvar: {
      hjelpe_til: hjelpen,
      teste: testen,
      merknad: merknaden,
      bilde: bildet,
      samtykke: samtykket,
      innmeldingsdato: innmeldingsdatoen
    },  
    Foresatt: {
      foresatt_navn: [
        {
          value: navn1
        },
        {
          value: navn2,
        },
        {
          value: navn3
        },
        {
          value: navn4
        }
       
      ],
      foresatt_epost: [
        {
          value: epost1
        },
        {
          value: epost2
        },
        {
          value: epost3
        },
        {
          value: epost4
        }
      ],
      foresatt_mob: [
        {
          value: mobil1
        },
        {
          value: mobil2
        },
        {
          value: mobil3
        },
        {
          value: mobil4
        }
      ]
    },//foresatt
  },//CustomSchemas
 password: passord
}; //var user
user = AdminDirectory.Users.insert(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all I need is a little break away from the code... I suddenly dawned on my that I could do the if earlier in code:

```
var epostForesatt = "{value:"+ epost1+"}"; 
if (epost2 != '') {
  var epostForesatt = epostForesatt + ",{value:"+ epost2+"}"; 
}
if (epost3 != '') {
  var epostForesatt = epostForesatt + ",{value:"+ epost3+"}"; 
}
if (epost4 != '') {
  var epostForesatt = epostForesatt + ",{value:"+ epost4+"}"; 
}
```

And then later in, down in "var user customSchemas" I edit the code to to use this variable.

```
Foresatt: {
      foresatt_navn: [
        {
          value: navn1
        },
        {
          value: navn2,
        },
        {
          value: navn3
        },
        {
          value: navn4
        }
       
      ],
      foresatt_epost: [epostForesatt],
```